# Updating index values on nan values from another index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`:

```
            2020        2021        2022        2023

A           50          60          nan         nan
A.2         50          60          0           0     # alternate version
B           500         600         0.7         0.8
```

I am trying to update the `nan` values on `A` from `B` so that the result would look like this:

```
            2020        2021        2022        2023

A           50          60          700         800
```

I tried:

```
df.loc['A'] = df.loc['A'].fillna(df.loc['B']*1000) # need to multiply the value by a 1000 before updating
```

But the values on `A` do not change, where is my mistake?

Comment: `I am trying to update the nan values on A from B` - so also are changed `2020, 2021` ?

Comment: Sorry, mistake, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is problem `nan` are strings, not `np.nan`:

```
#convert columns to numeric
df = df.astype(float)
#alternative if first method failed
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

df.loc['A'] = df.loc['A'].fillna(df.loc['B']*1000)
print (df)
    2020   2021   2022   2023
A   50.0   60.0  700.0  800.0
B  500.0  600.0    0.7    0.8
```

For converting row separately:

```
df.loc['A'] = df.loc['A'].astype(float).fillna(df.loc['B']*1000)
```

Comment: And what if instead `nan` I have `0` as `int` which I would like to replace the same way as `nan`? I added `A.2` alternate version which I would to change the same way.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - simpliest is replace `df.replace(0, np.nan)`